# Sharp Network Printer/Scanner Will Only Add as a Scanner. No Printing Functionality

Tags: drivers, printer, network-printer, scanner

I am attempting to diagnose an issue on an employees machine but have had no luck. Their particular machine stopped being able to print to the particular printer yesterday. I checked it this morning and flushed the print queue, restarted the printer, uninstalled the device and drivers from the PC and reinstalled everything. Now the PC will only recognize the printer/scanner as a scanner with no printing functionality. When I attempt to discover it, it shows as a printer but as soon as it installs it immediately changes to a scanner. No other machines are having this issue.
Anyone seen this before?

Comment: The printer and scanner are actually completely different pieces of hardware from Windows' point of view even if they are bundled together.  Before continuing, make sure the drivers for the printer side are installed on that machine (even if it IS supposed to be automatic).  Open printers and scanners -> Print Server Properties -> look at the drivers tab.  This will at least let you know if you have the driver or not.

Comment: Some inkjet printers are disabled if the waste ink pad counter reaches a limit. Some printers are automatically disabled if unauthorized toner or ink is inserted. There are many reasons the printer may have stopped working. Try it using another PC to see if the issue is in the printer or the PC.